# asp net core post request via consile application c#

Tags: c#, webapi

I know this is a common question, but after a long time I can't find a solution I would love to get help.
I need to send a post request to asp net core web api using console application c #.
I need to send an object to the request body.
The code I use doesn't work.
Many thanks in advance

this is the object:

```
public class Data1
    {
        public List<int> list { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
```

this is the requset from console application

```
 Data1 d1 = new Data1() { id = empId, list = result.Item3, url = splitremoteUri[0] };
 string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d1);
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   var result3 = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:59617/api/regular", output).Result;
}
```

this is the controller:

```
 [HttpPost("regular")]
        public void checkRegular( [FromBody] Data1 d)
        {
            iScopeDic.checkRegular(d.id,d.list, d.url);
        }
```

It doesn't work, I want to know what my mistake is.

Comment: Try passing Data1 object without serializing it like this: `var result3 = client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:59617/api/regular", d1).Result;`

Comment: I tried it, it not work.

Comment: *"doesn't work"* is not specific enough, and is not a meaningful problem description for SO. Do you get an exception? Does the debugger stop at breakpoints in the controller when the request is made? Have you stepped through the code in both the client and the server and verified that the data is being serialized and deserialized correctly at each step? Please be very specific about your observations of the data and the sequence of events.